# Images are cracked

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Images are cracked.
I wrote in photo.html,

```
{% extends "registration/accounts/base.html" %}
  {% block content %}
  <div class="container">
      <h2 class="page-header">{{ photos.title }}</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="/media/{{ photos.image }}">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'accounts:upload' photo.id %}">UPLOAD</a>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I do not know why.How can I fix it? Is "img tag" wrong?

The meaning of "cracked " is like
[image]

Comment: maybe its cause of your `class="img-responsive"`?

Comment: what do you mean by cracked?

Comment: @ZagorodniyOlexiy thx,ur comments.So,what should I do to fix it?

Comment: @EvansMurithi thx,ur comments.I added the situation info.

Comment: The path to your image file is incorrect so the browser cannot find them.

Answer (score 0):

Check the image url generated when the `DOM` is ready.

- Click on the broken image icon.
- Right click > Inspect Element
- Check the url.

If url is correct.. Check the network request panel .. to confirm whether the image is loaded or not.

Their may be some errors.. Like image not found on server.. or CORS issue.

Comment: thx ur comments.I checked the url,so I found src was wrong.
Images are in image(child app name)/images,so I wanna designate the directory,but I do not know how to do so.Would you tell me the way?

Comment: didn;t get the folder structure exactly.. however you can use `../` in front of src to go one directory back .. like `src="../media/{{ photos.image }}"`

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML markup should look like this:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="photo.image.url">
```

Answer (score 0):

`photos.image` references the image file itself and not the url to the image.
You need to use the image url `photo.image.url`:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ photos.image.url }}">
```